# Django for/if in template

Tags: javascript, django, dictionary

I have a simple question, but at the moment I'm to dumb to solve it.

I have different lists passed from a view to a template to create data for a googletable. It's working quite well and looks like the following:

```
        var input_class = 'bc';

        if(input_class == 'ab') {
            var rawData = [['ab'],
                        {%for ab in ab_list%}['{{ab}}'],
                        {% endfor %}];
        }
        else if(input_class == 'bc') {
            var rawData = [['bc'],
                        {%for bc in bc_list%}['{{bc}}'],
                        {% endfor %}];
        }
        else {
            var rawData = [['cd'],
                        {%for cd in cd_List%}['{{cd}}'],
                        {% endfor %}];
        }
```

For obvious reasons I want to put it in something like the following:

```
        {% for key, value in filter_lists.iteritems %}
            {% if input_class == '{{key}}' %}
                var rawData = [['{{key}}'],
                    {% for item in value %}['{{item}}'],
                    {% endfor %}
                ];
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Sadly it does not work. The keys are all strings like 'ab', the values are all the same lists as in the working example.

Thanks for help, Jakob.

---

EDIT:

- I'm using python 2.7, django 1.11
- input_class is changed by a dropdown-menu which is created by a list. The same list is defining the keys of the dict.

Comment: Try `items` and not `iteritems`.

Comment: What is changing `input_class`? Is it set by the user on the page, eg by some kind of input? Are you expecting it to change dynamically via JS?

Comment: items does not work too

Comment: Edited main post to your question @DanielRoseman

Comment: But what I mean is, are you expecting that value to change dynamically when the user changes the dropdown menu? Because if so that can't possibly affect the values in the Django template tags.

Comment: No the values are all passed with the dict, with change of the dropdown list it should only be changed which one of the values is shown.
In first solution I had a few lists, all of them were passed to the template, and if the dropdown menu had another choice selected, another list is shown. This worked perfectly.
All I wanted to do was pass all the lists together in a dict.
I think it's a simple syntax error, but I'm not getting the right solution by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself, but don't know why other versoin is not working.. problem seems to be the if statement..

```
        {% for key, value in filter_lists.items %}
            if (input_class == '{{key}}'){
                var rawData = [
                    ['{{key}}'],
                    {% for item in value %}['{{item}}'],
                    {% endfor %}
                ];
            }
        {% endfor %}
```